# Sufficiently random sample

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $d$ be an integer $\geq 2$, and let $\Omega = \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^d$,  $A \subseteq \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^2 $ and $i,j$ integers with $1 \leq i < j \leq d$. If we select an element $(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_d)$ in $\Omega$ randomly, the probability $p(\Omega,i,j,A)$ that $(x_i,x_j)\in A$ is exactly $\frac{|A|}{4}$.

If $\Omega'$ is a subset ("sample") of $\Omega$, we may similarly define $p(\Omega',i,j,A)$. We say that $\Omega'$ is an efficient substitute for $\Omega$ if $p(\Omega',i,j,A)=p(\Omega,i,j,A)$ for all $i,j$ and $A$.

We denote by $f(d)$ the smallest possible size for an efficient substitute for $\Omega$. We have the trivial bound $f(d) \leq 2^d$ (take $\Omega'=\Omega$) and , for example, $f(3)=4$
(take $\Omega'=\lbrace (x,y,x+y-2xy) |(x,y) \in  \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^2  \rbrace$). What is the value of $f(d)$ in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the question. You are actually asking, what is the smallest finite probability space (in size of $\Omega'$) on which one can have $d$ distinct pair-wisely independent (but not necessarily independent) events of probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Just to explain the reformulation: once the $i$-th event is defined to be
$$E_{i}=\lbrace\omega\in\Omega'\;|\;\omega(i)=1\rbrace,$$
the "efficient substitute" criterion amounts to $\mathrm{Pr}(E_{i})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathrm{Pr}(E_{i}\cap E_{j})=\frac{1}{4}$ for every $i,j$ with $1\le i,j\le d$ and $i\not=j$. The example for $d=3$ is a [well known case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence) of this situation.

Now, every such space satisfies $|\Omega'|=4n$ for some natural $n$ (the reason being obvious). Knowing this, we could ask an inverse question: given a $4n$-set $\Omega'$, what is the maximum size of a family $\mathcal{F}$ of $2n$-subsets of $\Omega'$ such that every two of them have intersection of size $n$. Knowing a precise answer to this, the original problem is solved as well: given a $d$ take the smallest $4n$ such that the maximum size of $\mathcal{F}$ is at least $d$.

There is a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WDY-4K5SSV9-2&_user=10&_coverDate=11%252F30%252F2006&_alid=1751979224&_rdoc=3&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_zone=rslt_list_item&_cdi=6779&_sort=r&_st=13&_docanchor=&view=c&_ct=11541&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=f7d789c702d869ebb39ba6aed9d790e2&searchtype=a) titled "Pairwise intersections and forbidden configurations". Let me quote from the abstract:

> Let $f_{m}(a,b,c,d)$ denote the maximum size of the family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of an $m$-element set for which there is **no** pair of subsets $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ with $|A\cap B|\ge a$, $|A^{c}\cap B|\ge b$, $|A\cap B^{c}|\ge c$, and $|A^{c}\cap B^{c}|\ge d$.

The count we are looking for is exactly $f_{4n}(n+1,n+1,n+1,n+1)$. Besides other interesting things, the paper gives also asymptotic estimates for this count; one of them gives $\Theta(4n^{2n-1})$ in our case.

Edit: unfortunately, I was too quick with the asymptotic estimate. The paper gives an estimate only for fixed $a,b,c,d$ as $m$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.ejc.2006.05.002](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2006.05.002) ([Zbl 1104.05068](https://zbmath.org/1104.05068)).

Answer (score 4):

You can find a set $\Omega$ with size $O(d)$. Assume for simplicity that $d=2^k-1$ for an integer $k$. Let $y_1,..,y_k$ be binary variables and define 
$x_j = \sum_i y_i \alpha_i(j)$ where $\alpha_i(j)$ is simply the $i$-th digit of $j$ when represented in binary. (For example, if $n=7$, you'll get $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_1+y_2, y_1+y_3, y_2+y_3, y_1+y_2+y_3$). You can get $2^k-1$ such linear combinations and they're all balanced and  independent - that is $Pr(x_i=1)=1/2$ and $Pr(x_i=a,x_j=b)=1/4, \: \forall a,b=0,1$.
This will satisfy the condition $p(\Omega,i,j,A) = |A|/4$. When $d=2^k-1$ this gives $f(d)\leq d+1$. For general $d$ (not be a power of two minus one) you should get $f(d) \leq 2d$ taking $d=2^k$ as the worst case.

Comment: BTDT: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7998/most-general-way-to-generate-pairwise-independent-random-variables/8084#8084

Also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59784/bound-the-tail-distribution/59801#59801

Comment: Reposting the links mentioned in the previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/163815) so that they appear in the "Linked" questions list: Ori Gurel-Gurevich's [answer to "most general way to generate pairwise independent random variables?"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8084) and [answer to "bound the tail distribution"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/59801).