# The power of two random choices with pairwise independence

Tags: pr.probability

Throw $n$ balls into $n$ bins, and let $X_n$ be the max load. That is the number of balls in the fullest bin.  It is known that if the balls are thrown uniformly and independently at random then $\mathbb{E}(X_n)  = \Theta(\lg{n}/\lg{\lg{n}})$.

If instead, for each ball considered sequentially we look at two bins chosen uniformly and independently at random, and throw the ball into the least full one (or a random one if they are equally full), then it is known that  $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = \Theta(\lg{\lg{n}})$, a dramatic decrease. See [this survey](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~ramesh/Site/PUBLICATIONS_files/MRS01.pdf) for example for more discussion of this phenomenon.

> If we still look at two bins for each ball and the bins are still selected uniformly but only with pairwise independence, what is a tight asymptotic upper bound for $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$?

We know that in the case of pairwise independence, if we just looked at one bin at a time, then a tight upper bound is $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Can you clarify the *pairwise independence* selection process you speak of?

Comment: [A curiously related question posted on math.SE at about the same time.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220292/example-of-pairwise-independent-random-process-with-expected-max-load-sqrtn)

Comment: @cardinal The random process I am thinking of samples integers from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ uniformly at random (but with only pairwise independence). Each sample represents a bin. In the "power of two choices" version, two samples are taken at each turn and both bins are inspected. A ball is then placed in the bin which is least full (or a random bin if they are equally full). The whole process terminates when $n$ balls have been placed into bins. Does this clear it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will Sawin's idea seems good. Here is a slightly simpler way to get a similar pairwise independent distribution where the maximum load with under a binary choice is still $\Theta(\sqrt{n}).$

Let $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$ be a random sequence of bins that is symmetric under permuting bins and indices so that a random set of about $\sqrt{n}$ balls go into one bin (at least $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ go into one bin, but a mixture may be needed), and the other balls go into distinct bins. This can be done so that the chance that two balls go into the same bin is $1/n$ so they are pairwise independent.

Choose a random permutation $\pi$ so that for any $i$, $\pi(i)$ is uniform. For example, we can choose $\pi$ to be uniform on $S_n$, or we can choose a random translation mod $n$.

Consider the sequence of pairs $\lbrace (x_i, \pi(x_i)) \rbrace$.

The first coordinates are pairwise independent by the construction of $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$. The second coordinates are pairwise independent by the symmetry of permuting bins and the pairwise independence of $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$. The probability that $x_i = \pi(x_j)$ is $1/n$ by the construction of $\pi$. So, these are pairwise independent.

Since at least $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ of the pairs are the same $(x,\pi(x))$, at least $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor/2$ balls have to go into either bin $x$ or bin $\pi(x)$, so the maximum load is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: This is really nice and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let me sketch why I think the answer is still $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Given any distribution such that, for each pair of the $2n$ random numbers, the probability that they are the same is $1/n$, we can symmetrize it by applying a random permutation in $S_n$.

Consider the distribution in which we choose $c \sqrt{n}$ of the $2n$ pairs at random. For each pair, we set one equal to $1$ and the other equal to $2$. This contributes $c /2n$ to the probability that two elements in different pairs are the same, and $0$ to the probability that two elements in the same pair are the same. Then let's balance that out by choosing $c/2$ pairs and setting both equal to $3$, contributing $c/2n$ to the probability that two elements in the same pair are the same. Then the elements we have not yet chosen can be distributed between $4$ and $n$ in such a way that they are less likely than normal to be the same, by ensuring that the numbers $4$ to $n$ each occur about the same number of times, and assigning those randomly. Choosing the correct number $c$ we should be able to balance the probability that two numbers are equal to be exactly $1/n$, or very close. Symmetrizing, we get an acceptable distribution (or we have to mix with a very slight quantity of a different distribution to get it exactly right.)

Then because we give the system $c \sqrt{n}$ choices between the same two bins, the max load is $c \sqrt{n}/2 = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Thank you! One possibly very silly question. Is your definition equivalent to a uniform distribution plus pairwise independence? I was thinking we might want for each pair of the $2n$ random numbers, the probability that the first is $x$ and the second is $y$ for $x \ne y$ is $1/n^2$. This seems a little stronger but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @dorothy - we do want that, but if we apply a random permutation, as long as the probability that the first is not the second is $1-1/n$, then as we distribute this among the $n^2-n$ different pairs, each pair will have a probability $1/n^2$.

Comment: Ah yes. I misread what you wrote originally. Thank you.

Comment: Of course this now leaves open the intriguing question of the minimal $k$-wise independence for which having two choices does improve the expected max load.

Comment: @dorothy Without pairwise, it's $n^{1/k}$, right?

Comment: Right. For $k$-wise independence it is $n^{1/k}$ for the worst case expected max load according to http://fr.arxiv.org/abs/1502.05729 .